# Gradient border of LinearLayout bottom and top not working as wanted

Tags: android, xml

I have written this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <!-- outer rect -->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <gradient
            android:angle="90"
            android:centerColor="#00000000"
            android:endColor="#88000000"
            android:gradientRadius="0"
            android:startColor="#88000000"
            
             />
</shape>
</item>
<!-- Inner rect -->
<item
    android:bottom="7dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:top="7dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Which provides for me the border at top and the bottom but the gradient which is set up in outer rectangle has too long radius. I don't know how to describe it clearly but I want less radius of gradient so then I can have border 7dp with "shadow". Check pictures it explains everything:

[image]

PS: In the picture on the left side it is without inner rectangle, just for explanation purpose. If I add inner rectangle it seems like outer rect. has border of one color, because gradient radius is too much. Hope you got me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this question was simple set background of my layout to 9patch image. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)